# Averaging values of all faces to shade a mesh one color

Tags: materials, eevee-render-engine

I'm ripping my hair over something this seemingly simple. Basically as shown in the image (the desired results are just two different materials set to black and white) I want to shade the object as one single color. However all the methods I've tried and research I've done are for cell shading, not whole object shading.

Basically when the object is mostly in shadow (or most of the faces are below a certain value) it should appear black, and when the object is in light (or most of the faces are above a certain value) the entire object should appear white.

My idea was to just use a shader to RGB node and use a color ramp to set the shade. But I can't make it clamp to the entire object and I've been trying random methods for hours now.

[image]